# how do I write a typescript declaration file for module that returns class instance

Tags: typescript

I am running into issues webpacking js modules that don't return values, and I am at my wit's end. So my approach is to now modify those modules to be more friendly to typescript and webpack.

Here is an example: [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable)

It defines the module as a UMD style module, but the factory function doesn't return any values. So when I import it, I have to use:

```
import "knockout-sortable";
```

typescript is emitting the import, but webpack is "optimizing" away the import so the module never gets loaded.

Internally, knockout-sortable creates three classes and assigns them to ko.bindingHandlers. From a user's point of view, each of these binding handlers has an options property that we can set various options on. So I figured that it would be good for the module to return a structure with the three instances in it. I put this at the end of the factory function:

```
return { 
   sortable: ko.bindingHandlers.sortable,
   draggable: ko.bindingHandlers.draggable,
   droppable: ko.bindingHandlers.droppable
};
```

my expectation is that I will be able to then do this in the calling code:

```
import * as sortable from "knockout-sortable";
sortable.sortable.options = { ... };
```

this way, it is clear to the compiler and to the webpack optimizer that I am using the module so it should get included in the bundle.

My question is how do I create the type declaration file for this return value of the module?

This is what I started with but, although there is no error in the declaration file, my import statement is saying that there is no declaration file for the module. (if I remove everything except the declare at the top, then the import statement doesn't have a problem finding the declaration).

My tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
   {
        "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "typeRoots": [
          "../node_modules/@types",
          "typings"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "Scripts/",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "es5",
          "scripthost",
          "es2015.promise"
        ]
      },
      "compileOnSave": true,
    }
```

Here is what a very simplified version of the javascript module looks like:

```
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // AMD anonymous module
        define(["knockout", "jquery"], factory);
    } else if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
        // CommonJS module
        var ko = require("knockout"),
            jQuery = require("jquery");
        factory(ko, jQuery);
    } else {
        // No module loader (plain <script> tag) - put directly in global namespace
        factory(window.ko, window.jQuery);
    }
})(function(ko, $) {
    var sortable = 1;
    var draggable =  [];
    var  droppable = {};

    return {
        sortable: sortable,
        draggable: draggable,
        droppable: droppable
    };
});
```

Notice that the return from the module's factory method isn't a constructor, it is an actual instantiated object. If it was a constructor, then I would know how to create the type declaration, but the object is already created and returned at the point of import. (essentially this returned object is a global)

Answer (score 0):

Please comment me if this help in any way. If not i am sorry for losing your time. This is usual way to return public type.

```
  return {
    // Getter Methods
    getDraggable() {
      return ko.bindingHandlers.draggable;
    },
    getSortable() {
      return ko.bindingHandlers.sortable;
    },
    getDroppable() {
      return ko.bindingHandlers.droppable;
    }
  }
```

If "ko" is our global instance then factory returns only method (not new obj instance). That method return 'ko.bindingHandlers.droppable'.

Comment: HI @nikola, this doesn't really fit what I am trying to do. I am not returning a class from the module. I am returning references to already created objects. These objects represent singletons in the system, so we can't create new ones through a constructor. I need TS to know that the return value from the module are these exact three instances.

Comment: Maybe this is more interest for you : https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visual-ts-game-engine/blob/master/src/libs/ioc.ts . I try to help but still don't understand.

Comment: No, sorry that doesn't do it either. You are thinking in terms of writing TS code. But I am asking about how to write the declaration file for some existing JS code. I have JS code that instantiates a global object and returns it from the module factory function. I want to create a type declaration file for the module that tells TS that the module returns an already instantiated object.